# Python Binance - Why my dataFrame is not show up

Tags: python, arrays

I try to create array in python with same data from Binance api to store the data for 5 mins and 15 mins volume for each pair. However, the array/ DateFrame function is not work.

```
def get_volume(symbol):
trading_volume_5m = 0
trading_volume_15m = 0
prices = client.get_all_tickers()
for coin in prices:
if coin\['symbol'\].startswith(symbol) and coin\['symbol'\].endswith('USDT') == True:

                klines = client.get_historical_klines(coin['symbol'], Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE, "1 day ago")
                klines2 = client.get_historical_klines(coin['symbol'], Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "1 day ago")
                
                for history in klines:
                    trading_volume_15m = float(history[5])
                
                for history in klines2:
                    trading_volume_5m = float(history[5])
                
                print(coin['symbol'], trading_volume_15m, trading_volume_5m)

print(get_volume('BTC'))

df = pd.DataFrame(get_volume('BTC'))
df
```

Result

```
BTCUSDT 1203.72366 69.25412
BTCUPUSDT 129.31 0.0
BTCDOWNUSDT 259462.36 0.0
BTCSTUSDT 1414.99 1.24
None
BTCUSDT 1205.09047 71.14972
BTCUPUSDT 129.31 0.0
BTCDOWNUSDT 259462.36 0.0
BTCSTUSDT 1414.99 1.24
```

Is it something wrong?